# Photo has bright and darker on an aerial photo question

Tags: photos, photogrammetry

For those that work in photogrammetry world, my question is how can I correct this  old aerial photo that needed to be correct from a darker and bright black and white. I would have like to have both the same one black and white in either dark or bright.

I am not sure how to fix this black and white a easier way to do it ?

Is it possible for me to correct it from the right side into the left side to make the same one?

[image: 1938 Aerial Photo]

They are not mosaic. it is a digital file that i got from a contractor that scanned it from the film that was flown from 1938 on our national forest. It does not have coordinate system.
Here is the screen shot.

Comment: Do you have a graphics package? (example Adobe Photoshop?)

Comment: Actually I have ERDAS. Would that work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is close to something known as [Radiometric equalization](https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/pers/2009journal/february/2009_feb_193-200.pdf).

It is normally possible using professional softwares to parametrize and correct this in a semi-automatic way.

But you can also do it using whatever [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) image processing software you want, such as [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org) for example.

I just gave this latter software a 1 minute try:

[image: Gimp result]

I simply selected the bright part of the image and then apply such kind of curve transform on the input gray level (x-axis) of the [image histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram) to get the output gray level (y-axis):

[image: Curve transform]

This is mainly local histogram adjustment.

Notice it's not perfect; 1) you will never be able to recover information from over-saturated regions (in photography some people refer to this as [burned image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burned_(image)) which may also be an artistic effect called "high-key" that photographers can search for, in order to end up with images which tend to have most of their histogram pulled to the rightmost part) and 2) there is still an artifact at the limit between the two parts; you may correct it by spending more time to manually work on it, but this is a job in itself. No algorithms are perfect.

Then if you have to automate this kind of things, you'd better figure out if there is some systematic behaviour in your images, and then, try to get the transformation parameter and the region of the image to apply them. You can use libraries such as [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) for this [digital image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_processing) task.

Comment: Thank you for this however I have trouble understanding how to do this with the picture you are showing above. I was able to use ERDAS and it can do that but just needed understand the graph of histogram works.

Comment: I would recommend first reading out the wikipedia [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram) and related sources, even if not perfect, it's a good starting point. To dig more into it, you can read [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_begins/py_histogram_begins.html) OpenCV tutorial. Then, there are [many](https://tinyurl.com/y78mwz45) [many](https://tinyurl.com/ybo6hmpo) photography websites explaining it with example (keep in mind an RGB image has 3 channels, hence once histogram each).

Comment: I have ERDAS Imagine 2018 on my computer; however, I was able to use what you suggesting but I have trouble saving it to a new file.

Comment: Well, I was not able to save when I made the modify. I had to split the bright and dark images in a separate. Then I looked at the metadata and see that the bright one is a  16 unsigned bit and the dark image is a 8 bit unsigned .  I had to rescale the 16 bit into 8 bit and then mosaic it back into a single image